# Overriding post's font-family

Tags: plugins, visual-editor, fonts

I have several users posting on my page. Some of them like to prepare post in Word and then copy-paste it into the WordPress Editor. Word uses custom inline CSS anc I'd like to get rid of the part which is changing the font family.

Is it possible to replace/remove font-family css from all the posts already posted (I don't want to use some filter when outputting post to the page or using some CSS combined with !important). Solutions like "don't use Word" or "tell them to stop changing the font" won't help. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a standard, up-to-date install of Wordpress? I can't actually get it to behave in this way, pasting to the editor from Word only carries over fairly basic formatting (bold, lists, italic etc)

Comment: @toby1kenobi it is standard. When I tried I had no success too, so I thought its something with my Word or browser. I don't know if they are using any kind of extension in their browser or what. I'll go and check it at their end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run a regex. Since they're continuing this behavior, you will probably want to create a custom plugin and set up a cron job to trigger it periodically so it will continue stripping all inline styles.

Your plugin will need to query all posts. From there, in a loop that checks each post's content, use

`preg_replace('style="*.*?"', '', $content);`

which will replace each inline style with nothing (''), essentially deleting it.

Comment: This would essentially remove text-align property too. With some modifications, the regex solution seems OK. Thanks.